# How to include .aspx and its content into a .cshtml view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm kinda new on .net and I ignored the existence of Controllers, Routing and Views and I already created my pages and their code behind on .aspx files and I want to know if there's some way to include in a cshtml view what I've already done on my .aspx files, or if I can redirect the view to my .aspx page without modifying my url. Thanks

Comment: There may be some examples/tutorials available online for how to simultaneously use WebForms and MVC in the same project.  But in general it's likely a lot more trouble than it's worth.  If you've built an entirely new application and already decided on which technology you want to use, why not continue to use it?  If you want to migrate to a newer technology, why not migrate to it?  Trying to use both simultaneously means you probably won't be using either one effectively.

Comment: Hi David, it's mainly because the advantages I found in MVC modifying the URL to be more search friendly  compared to .aspx

Comment: A quick Google search for "webforms friendly urls" finds some promising results.  You might start there and see if you can just use an existing library designed for what you want to do rather than drastically change your entire architecture.